# Automatically mapping associations in Mongoid using params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid and when I `.update_attributes` on a model that has a `references_one` using params[:model_name] I get the error...

```
@model.update_attributes(params[:model_name])
    undefined method `associations' for "...":String
```

I understand why this is happening.  Mongoid is trying to map that `.association_name` to the string value in the params hash when what it wants is a reference to another Mongoid::Document.  That I get.

**What I'd like to know is if there is a global way to fix this.**  For the moment I've gotten around this issue by doing something like the following...

```
model_params = params[:model_name]
if model_params.has_key? :relationship
    model_params[:relationship] = RelatedModel.first(:conditions => { :_id => model_params[:relationship] })
end
```

This works *but* I'd rather have a fix that fixes it every time so that I'm not manually mapping the related model every time I do an update.  That would defiantly be a violation of DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample module that you could include in all your models

```
module MyAppBase  
def my_update_attributes(model_params,related_model)
    if model_params.has_key? :relationship
        model_params[:relationship] = related_model.first(:conditions => { :_id => model_params[:relationship] })
    end
    self.update_attributes(model_params)
  end
end 

#include it in your model classes
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    include MyAppBase
    #normal model code
end
```

Comment: Except of course RelatedModel would have to be passed in as well.  I suppose this is a decent approach.  I'll have to play around with it.